# Is python-oauth2 the right tool for my issue?

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0

I'm coding an app which has to use [this api](https://www.scoilnet.ie/scoilnet-api/api-documentation). So I want to do at a certain point a search on their database. Now I'm struggling with which python library is the right one to use in order to authenticate about oAuth2? I couldn't find any by now, where I was sure, it would offer the necessary functions.
I wonder if [this library (python-oauth2)](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) offers, what I need. But this isn't a library for the client, is it? It seems it is for the server...

I'd be really grateful, if someone could just give me an advice, with what I should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

You will need to use the following modules. No need to use oauth. Just need to get the token before performing any search using the api.

> requests, json, urllib

Here's a short Example code for that

```
import requests, json, urllib

BASE_URL = "http://scoilnet.com/grants/apikey/"
r = requests.post(_BASE_URL+"user/token/", data={'username': username , 'password': password })
print r.getcontent
```

The above code will show you how to request a token from the api. Using that token you will be making get and post requests to the api which will give a json response. That json response will be shown as a Dictionary from which you will load you data in your program.

**Method 2**

You can also use urllib or urllib2 or urllib3

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as far as I know I need to use the oAuth2 authentication. Their Website also says so... and the url you took as `BASE_URL`, it's supposed to be the grant type.

Comment: I define the variable as global which contains the url. Also this variable will contain your api link and I just took that link for example only.

Comment: But still I need to authenticate via oauth2. Since you dont even use a `username` and `password`, but `client_id` and `client_secret`...

Comment: @JulianBerger I visited the api website you provided in your question. You should be using "python-oauth2 0.7.0" for the api. And here's a tutorial to do so [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-oauth2/0.7.0)